# Unable to run serverless framework in flask to create flask api

Tags: python-3.x, flask, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a flask api in aws lambda using serverless framework.But when i try to launch application using sls wsgi serve command in local then i am getting error as

Serverless: Using Python specified in "runtime": python3.6
Unable to import werkzeug (run: pip install werkzeug)

I installed werkzeug package and it is in both requirement.txt file and in python environment also.